# как-то в инспекторе выбрать метод

Tags: c#, unity3d

Мне нужно как-то в инспекторе выбрать метод. Ну как допустим в Button в инспекторе, внизу менюшка где можно добавлять-убавлять обьекты. Как это можно реализовать?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для возможности выбора методов, как в Button, воспользуйтесь классом UnityEvent:

```
public UnityEngine.Events.UnityEvent MyUnityEvent;
```

Использование "выбранного метода" будет иметь следующий вид:

```
MyUnityEvent.Invoke();
```